# R: Way to Remove Names on X Axis That Were Not Plotted (Leaving Names That Were)?

Tags: r, plot

I have this code that gets the top 10 frequencies and makes a plot:

```
top_n(data.3, n=10, (Frequency)) %>% barplot(Frequency~ICD10Code, data = .,cex.name=.5)
```

The issue that arises, that didn't occur to me at the time, is that it does plot the 10 most frequencies but it also includes all the ICD10Code names that were not plotted.

[image]

Is there a way to utilize the existing code perhaps without using`xaxt='n'` and/or `axis()` to where only the 10 most frequent ICD10Codes and respective frequencies are shown on plot?

Comment: I think some of your question got cut off, please edit for clarity

Comment: Is ICD10code by coincidence a factor (I think I saw another question where it was)? Did you try to make it a simple character (with droplevels).

Comment: @Annet Yes, it is. I am not sure of what you mean in regards to making it a simple character with drop levels or probably more appropriate, not sure I know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the names are still there because they are levels in your factor, so it still recognizes them. If you make it a character variable the levels should dissappear.

```
top_n(data.3, n=10, (Frequency)) %>% 
     mutate(ICD10Code = as.character(ICD10Code)) %>%
     barplot(Frequency~ICD10Code, data = .,cex.name=.5)
```

If it for some reason still displays as factor, than change the mutate to `mutate(ICD10Code = as.character(droplevels(ICD10Code)))`

Comment: Worked like a charm. As a new contributor, I am glad I can help you get that score up quickly!! Stayed tuned. . .I'm sure I will have more.