# R Trying to get frequency output on a factor variable, but ONLY for values that exist, not every factor label that exists

Tags: r

So, in SAS, when you run proc freq, the output shows you only the values in the data, not all formats available in the format and which ones have data and which ones don't.

I have a lot of variables that are factor, that i need to run freqs on, but because of the factor thingy, i'm getting a lot of 0s.  I've been using summarytools freq, and tried to google for other freq options, but nothing is giving me what i want.

What i have:

```
                                        Freq   % Valid   % Valid Cum.   % Total   % Total Cum.
------------------------------------- ------ --------- -------------- --------- --------------
                                 MPLP      0      0.00           0.00      0.00           0.00
                                 MIRC      0      0.00           0.00      0.00           0.00
                   Family Law Project      0      0.00           0.00      0.00           0.00
                            Washtenaw      0      0.00           0.00      0.00           0.00
                               Monroe      0      0.00           0.00      0.00           0.00
                              Jackson      0      0.00           0.00      0.00           0.00
                              Lansing      5      1.94           1.94      1.47           1.47
                          ATJ-Lansing      0      0.00           1.94      0.00           1.47
```

What i want:

```
                                        Freq   % Valid   % Valid Cum.   % Total   % Total Cum.
------------------------------------- ------ --------- -------------- --------- --------------
                              Lansing      5      1.94           1.94      1.47           1.47
```

Is there any frequency option in R that will show ONLY factors that have actual values?

Changing the variables from factor to something else is not an option at this point.  So it'd have to work on factors specifically.

Thanks

Comment: Could you share a sample of your data in R so that we can use it to better understand your question and how to help you? Thanks! (Recommend `dput(data)`)

Comment: If you want to do any analysis on factors, R takes into account all levels. So if you do not want that, for example when a level does no longer exist in your data, just mutate the factor so that it is a normal character or numeric variable. The levels that do not exist will be dropped.

Comment: @Annet what do you mean by mutate?  I've only been working in R for about 2 months and it's all self-taught.

Comment: Just convert it, like you can convert numeric to character etc. I do not know what your factor name is, but in base R it would be df$factor <- as.character(droplevels(df$factor)). If you want to use the `dplyr` package you can do it like df <- df %>% mutate(factor = as.character(droplevels(factor)).
see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326914/r-way-to-remove-names-on-x-axis-that-were-not-plotted-leaving-names-that-were/59327324#59327324

Comment: @Annet Thanks!  That worked.  So, basically, it can't be done on factor variables, i have to recode all of the factor variables into something else instead?

Comment: @Annet So, out of curiosity, when i have a categorical variable that starts as values and i want to add value labels, what's the best way to do it?  I've been doing factor because it was the first thing i found and if memory serves, something i wanted to do on a non-factor variable wouldn't work unless it was a factor.  Can't remember now.  How do you add labels for categorical variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problem is that R inherits the levels from a previous dataset or previous mutations (i.e., changes you made). This means you are left with some empty labels/levels for that factor. For your analyses you want to remove those empty labels.
This can be achieved in various ways.

**1.  Do it for each variable seperately**
which in base R would be:

```
df$factor1 <- as.character(droplevels(df$factor1))
df$factor2 <- as.character(droplevels(df$factor2))
```

or with the `dplyr` package (the %>% is symbol for piping):

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(factor1 = as.character(droplevels(factor1),
                    factor2 = as.character(droplevels(factor2))
```

However, if you have multiple of factors you will have to do a lot of typing.

**2. Do it for all factors simultaneously**

This is most easily done using the 'dplyr' package

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate_if(is.factor, ~as.character(droplevels(.)))
```

You use the mutate_if statement to select all variables that are of the class is.factor, than you apply a certain function on it. Here I chose to make it a character, but if you want to keep it as a factor it is also possible. Than use `~levels(droplevels(.))`.

Concerning your curiosity question, I do not think I can explain it any better than [this site](https://www.dummies.com/programming/r/how-to-create-a-factor-in-r/). Here it is explained how you can create factors with levels.